# find crossing line through 3 points on horizontal lines

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry

Given a group of n points which are spread on 3 horizontal lines (y=0 , y=1, y=2)
think of algorithm to find if there is crossing line with O(n^2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRsvQ.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your specific problem? Show us your code!

Comment: no need of a code, just the idea...
the regular solution would be to run all the points on y0*y1 and finding if there is needed point (binary search) on y2

so the run time would be:
n^2*logn

Comment: You have no space limit, so consider some data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this algorithm in O(n^2). First we assume:

1. The `x`-coordinates of the points on the line `y=2` can be represented by a finite number of bits.
2. That these x-coordinates are initially sorted in `x`. If not, then sorting them first is O(nlog(n))
3. The definition of the crossing line is made with respect to the precision of representing the points with the finite number of bits.

Now, construct a hash function as follows:

1. Find the minimum distance between adjoining points on the line `y=2`. Since the `x`-coordinates are sorted, this is O(n). Call this min distance `d`.
2. The hash function is floor(2*x/d). It is clear that this hash will map each point on `y=2` to a unique bin. This operation is also O(n).

Then, do the following:

1. For each pair of points on the lines `y=0` and `y=1`, compute its intersect on `y=2`. This is O(n^2).
2. For each intersect point on `y=2`, lookup the hash table to see if there is a point from the line `y=2` there. If there is, see if it is the same point (within precision of machine), and if so, then there is a crossing line. Otherwise, there is not. This is O(n^2) since the hash lookup is O(1).

Therefore, the algorithm is O(n^2). No code, just ideas.